# Check html page every x seconds

Tags: java, android, service, notifications, reload

I'm programming an app that will display the result of a team. I'd like notify the user when there's a goal. To do this, I created a service where I'll take the score and put it in a String every 30 seconds and I'll create a notification if it changes. My question is: What's the best way to repeat this every 30 seconds ?

Thank's and sorry for my poor english

Comment: Google for *polling*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like :

- check if anything changed (yes - send new info, no - do nothing)
- sleep 30 sec (`Thread.sleep(30000)`)
- repeat

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want to do a call every x seconds that would require an [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) setTimeout ([not setInterval](http://reallifejs.com/brainchunks/repeated-events-timeout-or-interval/)). If you are going to do that it would be a good idea to send back some data to the db each round trip to make sure your query is not massive, and searching the entire db table.

For example you might send back the most recent timestamp on each round trip. And then have the backend query check how many rows are greater then that timestamp and display the count to the user. So if there is one row, show the user `1 new row`. And when they click it query for the content. This should be a low impact query for a high impact activity (pooling would be a better option). Goodluck.

PS: If you want to get fancy and really learn some stuff tonight I would do some research on [asynchronous servlets](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/async-servlet/async-servlets.html), rather then just pooling as another poster advised. That would lead you down the rabbit hole to some really sweet stuff.